# DSA algorithm - digital signature

Tags: java, dsa

Last day I've spent on looking for correct Java implementation of DSA without using the java.secure and any other java.secure alike libraries(I've already used java.secure many times).

I googled, went on wiki, but couldn't find precise and clear description. If you have its implementation please share. It is not homework - school's out for summer, but this will help me very, very much.

I've already done the RSA but DSA is bigger deal to me.

Thank you for your help!

DSA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm

Comment: Why specifically are you trying to avoid using the libraries that would make this implementation far easier? Are you trying to learn how to do the mathematics yourself? What brings you to this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure there's an implementation at www.bouncycastle.org

Comment: Thanks You! At a first glance can't find it. But when i wake up I will look for it more.

Comment: http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/package-index.html

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to checkout fips_186-3 spec from FIPS [website](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf). On it's appendix you can find very detailed steps for almost everything needed in DSA, although they're written by pseudocode